# Unexpected behavior of while loop in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, while-loop

Made something like this:

```
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a number between one and nine. \n";
        int oneandnine;
        std::cin >> oneandnine;
        if (std::cin.fail())
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(100, '\n');
            std::cout << "INVALID UNPUT!\n";
        }else if (oneandnine <= 9 &&  oneandnine >= 1)
        {
            break;
        }else
        {
           std::cout << "INVALID UNPUT!\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and when input is provided something like this `456aihdb`, getting something like this:

```
  INVALID UNPUT!
  Enter a number between one and nine.
  INVALID UNPUT!
  Enter a number between one and nine.
```

Why does it loop twice like this? is it because when the `456` is discarded and the rest `aihdb` isn't which causes it to loop again and skip a `cin` input?

Comment: If you're also looking for a way to fix something like this, read the data into a string, and you convert the string yourself to an integer.  With that, you have full control of testing validity of the input, instead of leaving it up to "the system" in doing these checks.

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly as you think it is.

The `fail` flag isn't set immediately, instead the formatted input operator reads the integer `456` into `oneandnine`, but doesn't set the `fail` flag since it's a valid integer value. That leads to the `else` case executing since `std::cin.fail()` is false and `oneandnine` is not between `1` and `9`.

The next iteration you read the invalid input and the `fail` flag will be set leading to the second error output.

---

One common way to handle validation is to read the whole line into a string, put that string into an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and use that to attempt to parse the input:

```
if (!std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    // Failure of some kind, could be EOF or something else
    // Probably best not to continue in this case
}

std::istringstream iss(line);

if (!(iss >> oneandnine))
{
    // Invalid input, report it as such
}

if (oneandnine < 1 || oneandnine > 9)
{
    // Invalid number, report it as such
}

// Correct input, continue with program
```

Note that input such as `6abc` will be considered valid by the above code. The `6` will be extracted into `oneandnine` and the `abc` part will silently be discarded. If that's not wanted there are other ways for the parsing (e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) if exceptions are not wanted). Do that instead of the `>>` extraction, but the rest of the code above should be fine.

Comment: Reading from an `std::istringstream` has exactly the same issue unless you check that the read operation consumed the whole stream

Comment: @AlanBirtles No not really. Because the user-input will have already been consumed by the `getline` call, which means such input is silently ignored.

Comment: I imagine the OP wants the entire input to be valid though, not to silently ignore invalid input

Answer (score -1):

`std::istream`'s `operator >>` doesn't read in whole lines. It reads until it finds an invalid character or whitespace, if it has found a valid character before the invalid character the read operation succeeds and the invalid character is left in the stream.

In your example the first iteration successfully reads `456` and leaves `aihdb` in the stream. This fails your range check and the second iteration then tries to read the remaining characters which fails as the first character isn't a number.

If you want to read whole lines use `std::getline` then parse the whole line into a number. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a number between one and nine. \n";
        std::string line;
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        int oneandnine;
        size_t pos;
        try
        {
            oneandnine = std::stoi(line, &pos);
        }
        catch ( std::exception& )
        {
           oneandnine = -1;
        }
        if (pos != line.size() || oneandnine > 9 || oneandnine < 1)
        {
            std::cout << "INVALID INPUT!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *`std::istream` doesn't read in whole lines* doesn't make much sense. Given the context do you mean *Stream operator `>>` doesn't read in whole lines*?

Comment: @user4581301 `operator>>` is part of `std::istream`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: But so is `std::istream::getline`.